# Why is LinkedList.get throwing a NPE

Tags: java

I had this weird case which was only happening in a production environment.

Basically we keep a history of recent options per user and then we retrieve them like so:

```java
LinkedList l_recent = ApplicationEnvironment.getUserRecentOptions(username);

for (int i = 0; i < l_recent.size(); i++) {
   l_recent.get(i); // When i == 2 throws a NPE
}
```

However the stacktrace is empty and the javadoc for the get method only describes one possible exception: `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if `index < 0 || index >= size`

Fortunately, this only happened to very few users and we fixed it by clearing the history of recent options.

But I am still interested in knowing why would this throw a NPE.

My only guess is that as this list is per user it may happen that the same user is logged more than once and then we may call the add or remove methods of LinkedList concurrently

#### Edit 1

Here is the complete code involved:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class App {
    static class Option {
        private String name;

        Option(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    private static final HashMap<String, LinkedList<Option>> userOptions = new HashMap<>();

    public static LinkedList<Option> getUserRecentOptions(String user) {
        LinkedList<Option> options;

        if (userOptions.containsKey(user)) {
            options = userOptions.get(user);
        } else {
            options = new LinkedList<>();
            userOptions.put(user, options);
        }

        return options;
    }

    public static void addRecentOptionToUser(String user, Option option){
        LinkedList<Option> options = getUserRecentOptions(user);

        for (int i = 0; i < options.size(); i++) {
            Option opt = options.get(i);

            if (opt.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(option.getName())) {
                options.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }

        options.addFirst(option);

        // Max 4
        if (options.size() > 5) {
            options.removeLast();
        }
    }

    public static void main() {
        LinkedList<Option> recentOptions = getUserRecentOptions("demo");

        for (int i = 0; i < recentOptions.size(); i++) {
            recentOptions.get(i); // Throws NPE when i == 2 (sometimes...)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this all the code? It seems like `l_recent = null` (or something equivalent) is happening somewhere.

Comment: Is this the real code, or a simplified version?  Is the NPE thrown by the call itself or inside `get`?

Comment: Could it be that ApplicationEvironment.getUserRecentOptions returns null?

Comment: You presumably do not call `List::get` and ignore the result. Show the **real** code (or at least, closer to "real" than this contrived example)

Comment: If this is executing in a multithreaded context, then there is more chance that as you mentioned l_recent could be null for a user, if you are resetting l_recent somewhere in the code.

Comment: By the way, iterating with indices on a linked list is inefficient. You have turned something that need only be `O(N)` into something that's `O(N^2)`. Use an iterator or an ArrayList.

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo: not if `l_recent` is a local variable as this code suggests. Again: this can't happen if the code is as OP claims it is ... that's why we need the real code or at least something closer to the real code.

Comment: @JoachimSauer ofcourse, we need the real code. It was just a suggestion based on how much code is provided.

Comment: Based on how much code is provided, it is pretty much evident that l_recent could be set to null somewhere in the code (and this is more likely executing in mulithreaded context), since he is saying NullPointer is coming when i==2

Comment: This is a simplified version of the code which produces the error. I will update the question with a full version showing al the methods which interact with the linkedlist.

Comment: @JoachimSauer  There you go, not a local variable..

Comment: `ApplicationEnvironment.getUserRecentOptions()` can not return null and yes ignoring the result will still throw the NPE that's why I'm sure the problem is with `LinkedList.get`

Comment: I am highly skeptical that the “stacktrace is empty.”  I think it’s more likely that the code is logging it improperly.

Comment: @VGR I think that was because the way I had to hotpatch the code in production to be able to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

So *not* `get(i)` being null. If you do `for (Object lri : l_recent) {` a ConcurrentModificationException might point to concurrency problems. Though, the LinkedList is kept shared in the user recent options, and probably often updated, so a LinkedList is too low level, not shareable.

Make an API that provides high level access: getLatest, getAndRemember, getListCopyOfAll.

That there is a NPE can be caused be serialisation/deserialisation or some interna of get, or a new List assigned. That there is no stack trace seems to point to something like context switch. But that all is not based on some profound knowledge on my side.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
l_recent.size() -1
```

in `for` loop
 method return size and list start with 0 point

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was indeed a multi threading problem, if I call `addRecentOptionToUser` many times from different threads the problem is reproduced, a NPE is thrown because the node is null.

The solution is obviously make this code thread-safe.

Thanks

Comment: Expected that. Cheers!